# Devise List User Documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to make a 'My Files' Page where the documents that users have uploaded are listed, but am having trouble filtering the documents per user.

Right now it is showing all documents uploaded, instead of the document associated with the user who uploaded it.

I use devise for users

I've tried to change the if statement to various different conditions but cannot seem to filter the documents associated with each user.

This is my code for the 'My Files' page:

```
<% @documents.each do |document| %>
     <% if @document = current_user.documents.find_by(params[:user_id]) %>
        <%= link_to document.title, document %>: <%= link_to "Download", document.pdf(:original, false) %>
     <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This is my documents controller code for the myfiles page:

```
def myfiles
    @documents = Document.all
end
```

Is there a simple way I can filter the documents that are associated with each user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method will show documents associated with current user only.

Controller file:

```
def myfiles
 if current_user
   @documents = current_user.documents
 else
  @documents = Document.all 
 end
end
```

View file:

```
<% @documents.each do |document| %>
 <%= link_to document.title, document %>: <%= link_to "Download", document.pdf(:original, false) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails `find_by` returns the first record found. You're probably looking for `where`.

In the controller:

```
@documents = if params[:user_id]
  current_user.documents.where(user_id: params[:user_id])
else
  Document.all
end
```

In the view:

```
<% @documents.each do |document| %>
  <%= link_to document.title, document %>: <%= link_to "Download", document.pdf(:original, false) %>
<% end %>
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find_by
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where

Comment: This still shows all documents, not the documents associated with a single user

Comment: Where does param :user_id come from?